# How to plot on a symmetric axis/frame

Tags: plotting

Say one had a function that was itself asymmetric about the abscissa, but one desired to plot it on a symmetric ordinate. How can this be achieved with `Plot` automatically (without separately computing the limits and providing them to `Plot`)?

**Example**
The plot of `1/2` serves as a sufficient example.

```
Table[
  Plot[ 
    1/2, 
    { x, 0, 1 }, 
    Frame -> { False, True }[[i]], 
    Axes -> { True, False }[[i]] 
  ],
  { i, 1, 2 } 
 ]
```

[image: asymmetric plots]

But we might want the `PlotRange` to go from $+1$ to $-1$ instead, like:

[image: symmetric plot]

I did this with the option `PlotRange`, but short of finding the maximum of the absolute value of the function and setting `PlotRange`, I don't know how to automate this.

Specifically, is it possible to use `Plot` in a native manner to do this?

**Solution** (based on the answer by Szabolcs)
Here's a little function that implements the answer.

```
plotSym[ plot_ ] := 
  plot //
    { 
      #, 
      First[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]], 
      Max@Abs@Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]] 
    } & //
      Show[ #[[1]], PlotRange -> {#[[2]], (1.2*{-#[[3]], #[[3]]})} ] &
```

Note: I added the factor of `1.2` as a way to give the plot a little more room. It can be anything nonzero (including the likely more-desirable `1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try extracting the `PlotRange` using `AbsoluteOptions`.  You need to use `AbsoluteOptions`, not simply `Options`, to make sure `All` gets translated to a numerical value.

```
g = Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]

max = Max@Abs@Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]]

Show[g, PlotRange -> {All, 1.1 {-max, max}}]
```

Comment: Nice, thank you Szabolcs. I wrote a little  function based on your answer that I'll put in my question.